# Passing 2 fields values for the same variable in jphpmailer.php

Tags: php

how can I assign two different fields values for the same variable in jphpmailer.php? Here is my present code:

```
$reg_name = isset($_POST['lname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']): "";
```

I want to add one more field to it, like "fname", but my knowledge in php still not enough to solve it grammatically right.

```
$reg_name = isset($_POST['lname','fname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname','fname']):
```

Comment: String concatenation is done with `.`

Comment: $_POST['lname','fname'] this will cause parse error, this is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

```
echo $reg_name = (isset($_POST['fname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']): "").' '.(isset($_POST['lname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']): "");
```

Creating array as:

```
$reg_name['fname'] = isset($_POST['fname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']): "";

$reg_name['lname'] = isset($_POST['lname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']): "";

print_r($reg_name);
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, I am trying to assign two fields to the same varieble $reg_name

Comment: Are you trying to create an array.

Comment: Sorry, I could see the whole code line in your answer. So now I realize where was my mistake, when trying to make an array. Thank you very much, It worked, and I learned something.

Comment: nice to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with below code if it can solve your problem...

```
$reg_name = '';
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
   $reg_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
}

if(isset($_POST['lname'])){
    if($reg_name){
       $reg_name.=' '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
    }else{
       $reg_name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
   }
}

echo $reg_name;
```